# How can I run the file currently open in the kate editor as a python script?

Tags: scripting, shebang, kate

I am writing Python scripts and using a shebang line to specify the location of the Python interpreter in my system.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

So, in principle, my system should be able to run the script correctly, using the right interpreter.

This should also be true for other scripting languages, such as shell scripts, provided that I give the right path to the interpreter in the shebang line.

What I do now to run it is to open a terminal, and type:

```
python /path/to/my/script.py
```

but I am looking for a more efficient way.

So, my question is: is there a command, within Kate, which allows me to run the current file as a script?

I am trying the command "Run Current Document", under the "Tools" menu, I get a message asking if I really want to run it, but then nothing happens.

Comment: Are you aware of the konsole-plugin for kate? [see](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kate/kate/kate-application-plugin-konsole.html)

Comment: hello @FelixJN, yes, I am aware of it, but I see nothing in it...

Comment: What does the script do? How would you see its output if you run it from within the editor? Also, why are you using Windows paths? `\path\to\my\script.py` should be `/path/to/my/script.py` unless you're on Windows. Finally, if you have a shebang line, you can just save the script in a directory in your $PATH and run `script.py`, no need for the full path. And even with the full path, the shebang means you can run `/path/to/my/script.py`, there is no need to add `python`. Does any of this solve your issue?

Comment: thank you @terdon! this question is not referred to a specific script, and my scripts are supposed to have "print" outputs, and matplotlib "show".
I am aware of the things you say, about the path, and the $PATH; however, unfortunately, none of this solve my problem.